# Artifactory: Publishing Ivy Descriptors to Repository via Script

Tags: java, deployment, ivy, artifactory

It has been explained to me that if you want to have Artifactory manage your repository (which I do), and if you do not wish to hand-write your own Ivy descriptors yourself (which I don't), then your options are to either:

- Use Ivy RoundUp, which contains Ivy descriptors in addition to the artifacts themselves; or
- Write a script to generate the descriptors for you; or
- Write an XML transform to convert between Maven and Ivy descriptor schemas

After carefully weighing my options, I have decided to write a Python script to generate these descriptors.  I will place all the artifacts I wish to deploy/install to my repository into a `deploy/` folder, and the script will iterate over any artifacts it finds in this folder, query the user for information about it, and then **perform the deployment for me**, right there inside the script.

Although this last requirement is not mandatory, it would be *nice* to just have the script hit Artifactory's RESTful API and deploy the descriptor and the artifact for me, in the right location.

[This page](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12157616) explains the API, and is the topic of my question.

The only `PUT` based operation the API exposes is this:

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/artifactory/<repo>/<organization>/<module>/<version>/<artifact>:sample-metadata

<xml-metadata-content/>
```

The description for this operation is:

> Attach the XML metadata to an item (file or folder).

**Is this what I'm looking for?** For instance, if I have a jar called `my-utils-2.3.jar`, then I want to be able to place this in the `deploy/` directory, and have my script not only generate `my-utils-2.3-ivy.xml`, but to deploy both of these items to my repository at the right location (which, in this example, would be `http://localhost:8080/artifactory/my-repo/my/utils/2.3/`).

If this is not what I'm looking for, then does Artifactory's API even support what I want (and where is the documentation on this!)?

And, if it is what I'm looking for, then I have a 2nd security-related question. I would like to keep all of my repositories secured.  Ideally, the user executing this Python script would have to provide the Artifactory `admin` username & password in order for the deployment to carry out successfully.

But nowhere in this operation's definition do I see any support for authentication!! Am I to assume that Artifactory doesn't authenticate REST calls?!?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
I found the following example on the Artifactory/Users old nabble forum:

```
curl -X PUT -u user:password --data-binary @/absolute/path/my-utils-2.3.jar "http://localhost/artifactory/my-repo/my/utils/2.3/"
```

**Would this be what I'm looking for?** That way, I could use PyCurl for the curl/libcurl interface, and still achieve security. If so, then **why am I being asked for authentication by curl, as opposed to Artifactory?**

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, to create a python script that can deploy an artifact. Did you find any viable solution for a python implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifactory uses HTTP BASIC authentication for all REST calls. The curl example you mentioned will not work, since you need to specify the full target path for the *file* (the current command will just (re)create the directory in Artifactory and ignore the file stream). You should use:

```
curl -XPUT -f -uadmin:password --data-binary @/absolute/path/my-utils-2.3.jar "http://localhost/artifactory/my-repo/my/utils/2.3/my-utils-2.3.jar"
```

However, you can use Ivy to resolve directly from 3rd party Maven repos via the [IBiblio resolver](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/ibiblio.html) (see "usepoms"), or automatically convert poms to ivy descriptors using the [convertpom](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/use/convertpom.html) task.

Artifactory also allows you to apply this type of pom->ivy conversion internally and store the ivy file into its cache via a groovy-based [user plugin](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins) that intercepts the 'afterRemoteDownload' event.

Answer (score 0):

Although Artifactory is flexible enough to support ivy repositories, I would recommend running it as a Maven repository.

Why?

1. Maven has established itself as the defacto Java *repository* standard.
2. Other builds tools, Ivy, Gradle, sbt,etc all understand Maven repositories.

The following answer describes how ivy can deploy to a Maven repository:

[Convert ivy.xml to pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426011/convert-ivy-xml-to-pom-xml/9429286#9429286)