# Ivy- store "type"-attribute of artifact in Maven repository

Tags: maven, ant, ivy

I try to migrate from a legacy Ivy repository to a Maven self hosted instance (Artifactory) using Maven 2 compatible format. The legacy Ivy artifacts make use of all attributes that Ivy supports, to name it: "configuration (conf)", "extension (ext)", "type" and "name".

I can map most attributes to equivalents in Maven:

- "conf" -> "scope"
- "name" -> "artifactId"
- "ext"  -> "packaging"
- "organization" -> "groupId"
- "revision" -> "modelVersion"

But for "type" there no attribute left in the Maven artifact. The primary use of the "type" attribute is to control the artifacts deployment (where and how to deploy them).

I noticed that the Maven artifacts do not support "custom" attributes. So how could I store the "type" information in a standard conform way?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [ivy documentation](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/artifact.html)

> the type of the published artifact. It's usually its extension, but
>   not necessarily. For instance, ivy files are of type 'ivy' but have
>   'xml' extension

Unless specified the "type" of an artifact defaults to jar.

## Update

Maven supports different types of module artifact using classifiers. This can be emulated in ivy using [extra attributes](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/concept.html#extra).

Examples:

- [Convert ivy.xml to pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426011/convert-ivy-xml-to-pom-xml/9429286#9429286)
- [how to publish 3rdparty artifacts with ivy and nexus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111831/how-to-publish-3rdparty-artifacts-with-ivy-and-nexus/5115447#5115447)

Comment: Maybe my question is not elaborate enough, but I do know how and what Ivy does with the "type" attribute since I use it a lot :-). My problem is with rather with Maven, that does not have a similar attribute/property. In Maven you only have "packaging", which is is similar to Ivy's "ext" attribute. Since "ext" is pretty straight forward/fixed in Ivy, I am missing an additional attribute in Maven, so that I can store my current "type" information (such as a deployment path hint) in Maven, also.

Comment: @PeterBranforn Your observation is spot on. Maven has less options, when compared to ivy. What exactly are you using type for? It's not something I set in my projects.

Comment: I use the extra parameter to control the location to where the artefact parts are downloaded to. The important detail: since each ivy.xml contains multiple artefact parts, each is downloaded into a separate location depending on the "type" attribute.

Comment: @PeterBranforn What about using an ivy extra attribute instead? Specifically use a Maven classifier.

Comment: Hi Mark, the classifier is already used for the artefact "ext" declaration. I was reading a bit regarding "misusing" the attribute for something else, but that would basically break the compatibility with Maven-builds itself :-(.

Comment: @PeterBranforn Classifier is a Maven concept, so I would argue that using it increases compatibility with Maven repositories. Ivy and Maven managed modules quite differently. In Maven the only way to add an additional artifact is to specify a classifier. When querying Nexus, sometimes it returns a "type" attribute that appears to be the remote files extension. Problem is in Maven this "type" field is undocumented from what I can see, so best to ignore it when publishing artefacts.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for being ambitious to solve my issue, I really appreciate that! The link that you added ('how to publish 3rdparty artefacts with ivy and nexus') is what I used as a baseline for my ivy->maven transition. The problem is that the classifier has a very unique meaning; basically it is not attached to the artefact, instead is intended for a dependency declaration only. I tried adding a classifier to the original 'project' tag, which seemed not to be supported. Thus I would not be able to add this extra information to all artefacts, but only to my extra dependencies.