# Error when trying to use optional token in artifacts pattern

Tags: ivy

Up until now, I was only generating a `dist/imasUtils.jar` file in the build (using Ant), and publiching it with the following Ant code:

```
<ivy:resolve/>
<ivy:publish resolver="imas-ssh" overwrite="true" publishivy="true">
  <artifacts pattern="dist/[artifact].[ext]"/>
</ivy:publish>
```

So far, this worked, but now I want to publish also the source, so I am also generating `dist/imasUtils_src.zip`. [According to my understanding of the ivy manual](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/concept.html#patterns), I could do this:

```
<ivy:resolve/>
<ivy:publish resolver="imas-ssh" overwrite="true" publishivy="true">
  <artifacts pattern="dist/[artifact](_[type]).[ext]"/>
</ivy:publish>
```

and that would recognize both of my files `dist/imasUtils.jar` and `dist/imasUtils_src.zip`, the only difference is that when I published them the `type` attribute would be `null` for the jar file.

Instead, I am getting the following error message:

```
/[myDirectory]/build.xml:119: impossible to publish artifacts for net.conselldemallorca.imas#imasUtils;1.2.0:
java.io.IOException: missing artifact net.conselldemallorca.imas#imasUtils;1.2.0!imasUtils.jar
  at org.apache.ivy.core.publish.PublishEngine.publish(PublishEngine.java:225)
  at org.apache.ivy.core.publish.PublishEngine.publish(PublishEngine.java:172)
  at org.apache.ivy.Ivy.publish(Ivy.java:621)
  at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyPublish.doExecute(IvyPublish.java:311)
  at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.execute(IvyTask.java:271)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  ...
```

My `ivy.xml` file:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">

  <info organisation="net.conselldemallorca.imas"
    module="imasUtils" revision="${ivy.revision}"/>

  <publications>
    <artifact />
  </publications>
 </ivy-module>
```

and my organization `ivy-settings.xml` file:

```
<ivysettings>
  <property name="ivy.pattern" value="artifacts/[organisation]/[module]/r[revision]/ivy-[revision].xml" override="false"/>
  <property name="artifact.pattern" value="artifacts/[organisation]/[module]/r[revision]/[artifact].[ext]" override="false"/>
  <settings defaultResolver="shared"/>
  <resolvers>
    <ssh name="imas-ssh" host="MYHOST" publishPermissions="0770">
      <ivy pattern="/var/www/html/Ivy/${ivy.pattern}"/>
      <artifact pattern="/var/www/html/Ivy/${artifact.pattern}"/>
    </ssh>
    <chain name="shared">
      <url name="imas">
        <ivy pattern="http://ivy.proves.imasmallorca.net/Ivy/${ivy.pattern}"/>
        <artifact pattern="http://ivy.proves.imasmallorca.net/Ivy/${artifact.pattern}"/>
      </url>
      <ibiblio name="public" m2compatible="true"/>
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

I am using Apache Ant 1.9.3 and Ivy 2.4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem might be the way you've defined the "type" in the pattern. You also need to declare more than one file in your ivy file's publications section.

I suggest the following change to your ivy file:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">

    <publications>
      <artifact name="imasUtils" type="jar"/>
      <artifact name="imasUtils" type="zip" e:classifier="src"/>
    </publications>
```

And corresponding change in the publish task's pattern:

```
<ivy:publish .. >
    <artifacts pattern="dist/[artifact](_[classifier]).[ext]"/>
</ivy:publish>
```

The "classifier" is an example of a custom [extra attribute](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/concept.html#extra).

Example:

- [Convert ivy.xml to pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426011/convert-ivy-xml-to-pom-xml/9429286#9429286)

The following link provides more explanation on how ivy interacts with Maven repos which has a fixed understanding of a "sources" attribute.

- [how to publish 3rdparty artifacts with ivy and nexus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111831/how-to-publish-3rdparty-artifacts-with-ivy-and-nexus/5115447#5115447)

Comment: Thanks very much. In the end it worked, but I also had to change my ivysettings.xml to alter the artifact pattern.